# Rails 4 Dynamic Controller in routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-api

I am creating a rails api, and am attempting to keep a modular approach in my controller. As such, I have a few models - `Organization`, `Branch`, `User`. Let's say that `Users belong_to Organization`, and `Branches belong_to Organization`.

In a base controller that all other controllers extend, I want to have an `index` method that knows how to handle a few different routes:

`Organizations/1/branches` and `Organizations/1/users`.

That index method would be more beefy than the following, but this is the idea:

```
def index
    Organization.joins(params[:relation_one].to_sym).where(id: params[:organization_id])
end
```

And my routes would be defined like so:

```
scope '/organizations' do
  scope '/:organization_id' do
    get '/' => 'organizations#show'
    put '/' => 'organizations#update'

    scope '/:relation_one' do
      get '/' => ':relation_one#index'
      post '/' => ':relation_one#create'
      scope '/:relation_one_id' do
        get '/' => ':relation_one#show'
        put '/' => ':relation_one#update'
      end
    end
  end
end
```

How can I create dynamic routes similar to above in which the controller is dynamic based on the url route? Something similar to the above snippet should work for both `Organizations/1/branches` and `Organizations/1/users` without me specifically defining both routes. This API will have several relations like this down the road, so I want to come up with the right approach now.

Answer (score 1):

you could write up an array of the controller names and then run a loop in routes.rb

```
relations = [':relation_one', ':relation_two']
scope '/organizations' do
  scope '/:organization_id' do
    get '/' => 'organizations#show'
    put '/' => 'organizations#update'

    relations.each do |rel|
      scope "/#{rel}" do
        get '/' => "#{rel}#index"
        post '/' => "#{rel}#create"
        scope "/#{rel}_id" do
          get '/' => "#{rel}#show"
          put '/' => "#{rel}#update"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

you could create a constant that stores all controllers you want to have in an array and then just iterate through in your routes file

```
AVAILABLE_CONTROLLERS = [:organizations, :branches, :users]
AVAILABLE_CONTROLLERS.each do |cname|
  scope "/#{cname}" do
    scope '/:id' do
      get '/', :action => :show
      put '/', :action => :update

      scope '/:relation_one' do
        get '/' => ':relation_one#index'
        post '/' => ':relation_one#create'
        scope '/:relation_one_id' do
          get '/' => ':relation_one#show'
          put '/' => ':relation_one#update'
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```